# Is there anything wrong with this heat sink design?

Tags: heat, heatsink, thermal

If not, is it any better that the conventional fin-based heatsink? It attaches at the bottom, and looks exactly the same in the back. It is supposed to be a passive cooling type heat-sink, therefore there is no fan attached.
[image]

Comment: The top two-thirds is wasted material. If that part gets hot then the device has already exceeded specs.

Comment: Seriously!?  You haven't said where the hot thing attaches, what the back looks like, what the 3D structure actually is, whether there is air flowing thru some parts, etc.  Closing, and -1 since providing this basic information should have been obvious.

Comment: I added this information into the post.

Comment: Consider the cost of producing an object of this geometry as compared to a regular finned heatsink.

Comment: If the part is attached to the bottom, the thermal conductivity of that vertical pillar won't move much heat. It also won't work well in the orientation pictured as passive heatsinks work best when hot air can rise up through them drawing in more air from the bottom. But perhaps most importantly, what is the reason having a device of this shape, isn't it a bit like re-inventing the wheel or is there a particular reason?

Comment: To answer the question you asked, Yes.  =-D

Comment: @joshglen -- look into successful heatsink designs and compare their performances in different scenarios. Namely which geometries work better with more or less airflow, etc. This can give insights into what is valuable for a passive design. Also look at IR images of heatsinks. Extremely long fins (such as the circumferences) will conduct almost no heat at the extremes while blocking airflow.

Comment: Also, any passive device which requires horizontal air flow is just a disaster. Hot air wants to rise, and any good cooling design encourages it to do so, in order to carry heat away from the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a bad rendering of a dumb and wasteful design. The air channels are probably too narrow, the material should taper to the tips of the heat exchange areas etc. etc.. It could only be made by wire EDM or some similarly expensive process.

It it almost as if a heatsink was 'designed' by an artist rather than an engineer who understands Nusselt numbers, laminar vs. turbulent flow, etc. etc.